# Use DISTINCT on joined columns with Laravel Query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I've got two tables products and artifacts who are in a one-to-many-relationship to each other.

Now I'd like to query a few artifacts joined with the products-data.
This works very good like this:

```
$artifacts = Artifact::with('product')->get();
```

However now I'd like to use the DISTINCT command and select the necessary fields to consider with DISTINCT from both tables. Sadly all joined columns fail.

```
$artifacts = Artifact::with('product')->select('product.organization, revision')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: with('product') does not join anything, but fires second query on the products table with WHERE IN statement, so describe what exactly you want to use distinct on and is the relation artifact to many products or the other way?

Comment: there are duplicate artifacts I want to eliminate in the view that is rendered based on $artifacts. One product has many artifacts.

Comment: This query should by any chance return duplicates, so are you getting those or are you getting error/exception because there's no product.organization field? If there are dups, please paste the queries ( with eg. DB::getQueryLog() )

Answer (score -2):

```
return DB::table('artifacts')
        ->join('products','products.id', '=', 'artifacts.product_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Comment: Really, dammy as the name.